# How to add gsl to MinGW?

Tags: c++, mingw, libraries

I use TextPad and MinGW. I compile with TextPad so I don't know how to use gcc ect. comands.

I got my library from here ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gsl/gsl-1.9.tar.gz and I have no idea what to do with it. In my MinGW folder there are bin, include and lib folders of course but I have no idea what to copy where.

And I don't know how to find out where MinGW searches for these libraries.

It would seem reasonable to copy .h , .a and .dll files where such files already are. It doesn't help that supposedly the same gsl are different from source to source and some include .dll and some don't.

I suppose the biggest problem is how do I tell MinGW where to search, since I found gsl that is already compiled and I could supposedly already use.

Comment: Updated answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30015656/using-gnu-scientific-library-gsl-under-windows-x64-with-mingw).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have MSYS accompanied with MinGW, you can simply do:

```
./configure
make
make install
```

after

```
tar xzf gsl-1.9.tar.gz
cd gsl...
```

It will install gsl to the default directories. You may have to use -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib on the command line when compiling your program using gcc, because MinGW gcc does not recognize those standard locations.