# How to fix 'unknown type name' error when linking GSL library to Matlab MEX

Tags: c, matlab, mex, gsl

I am currently trying to optimize some code I am working on in MATLAB (version R2019a). To compute my results, MATLAB has to compute a certain function a lot of times, slowing down everything. Because of this, I thought writing this function in C and importing this into MATLAB would speed things up a lot. Unfortunately I ran in some troubles by trying to compile the C-code into MATLAB using MEX.

I have used C before, but am certainly not an expert. Anyway I've tested the code in C and it works, the problem lies in trying to compile the code in MATLAB. I am using the GNU Scientific Library (GSL) and should thus include the libraries in compiling with MEX in MATLAB.

The following is a minimal working example leading to the same problems and errors. The C-code looks something like this, saved in `MWE.c`

```
#include "mex.h" // The mex library
#include <gsl/gsl_sf_bessel.h> // GSL function

// Define some function, in my case this is somewhat more complicated
double bessel_fun (double *x)
{
    return gsl_sf_bessel_J0 (*x);
}

// MEX function needed for compiling in MATLAB
void mexFunction( int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    //declare variables
    mxArray *x_M, *y_M;
    double *x, *y;

    //associate inputs
    x_M = mxDuplicateArray(prhs[0]);

    //associate outputs
    y_M = plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1,1,mxREAL);

    // Access variables
    x = mxGetPr(x_M);
    y = mxGetPr(y_M);

    // Save the result in the output variable
    y[0]=bessel_fun(x);
}
```

I then compile in MATLAB using

```matlab
    mex -IC:/MinGW/include -LC:/MinGW/lib -lgsl -lgslcblas MWE.c
```

Instead of compiling (which does work if I use C-code *without* including any libraries), MATLAB returns a lot of errors, as follows:

```matlab
Error using mex
In file included from
C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2019a/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/stddef.h:7:0,
                 from
C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2019a/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/include/stddef.h:1,
                 from C:\MinGW\include/stdio.h:68,
                 from C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019a/extern/include/mex.h:38,
                 from C:\userpath\MWE.c:1:
C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2019a/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/crtdefs.h:35:19:
error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'typedef'
 __MINGW_EXTENSION typedef unsigned __int64 size_t;
                   ^~~~~~~
C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2019a/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/crtdefs.h:45:19:
error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'typedef'
 __MINGW_EXTENSION typedef __int64 ssize_t;
                   ^~~~~~~
C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2019a/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/crtdefs.h:52:9:
error: unknown type name 'size_t'
 typedef size_t rsize_t;

[...]
```

and the same error on different type names.

Does anyone have an idea how to correctly include the libraries when compiling with MEX in MATLAB?

Comment: How did you get your gsl version on your machine? Did you build it yourself? Have you considered using the binary distribution vs 2.2.1?

Comment: I downloaded the most recent version of [GSL](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/)  and installed it following the answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30029219/11261640). It works perfectly if I just compile the C-code with gcc, but not in Matlab

Comment: What version of MinGW is installed?

Comment: I am using the most recent `MinGW.org GCC-8.2.0-3` for compiling C. Matlab uses `MinGW GCC 6.3 from mingw-w64.org` (according to the [documentation](https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/52848-matlab-support-for-mingw-w64-c-c-compiler)
Could it have something to do with 32bit/64bit versions? Then again, the Matlab compiler works if I don't include any GSL libraries.

Comment: Thats why i was asking. You need the 64 bit version of course. size_t is otherwise undefined

Comment: Ah yes, this seems to be the problem. I've tried compiling with `mingw-w64`, and obtained the same errors as in MATLAB (as it also uses the 64 bit version). So do I need a 64 bit version of GSL? Does this exist?

Comment: Everything must be built for the corresponding aechitecture, yes

Answer (score 0):

Gotcha. Could you try the following please:

```
mex -U__MINGW_EXTENSION -IC:/MinGW/include -LC:/MinGW/lib -lgsl -lgslcblas MWE.c
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've tried it, and I still get the same errors of unknown type names.