# installing GSL library for C programming in windows

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, mingw-w64, gsl, vcpkg

I want to install the GSL library (https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/) in windows. I have downloaded the files but i do not know what to do apart from that in order to be able to use the functions of the library (apart from the #include <...> in my program.c file).
I am using visual studio code and i have installed mingw.

Thanks in advance

---

EDIT

I am adding more information about this issue. *I am not the original poster, but I have the same problem.*

I am trying to use the GSL and I work with Visual Studio Code on Windows 10.

I have already installed the basic packages to work with C/C++ in
Visual Studio Code. More precisely, if I am not wrong, VS Code is
using the compiler `gcc.exe` from `mingw64` (last version). This was
installed using an 'extension' available at VS Code (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools).

I downloaded the last version of the GSL (2.7) and unzipped it.

I get stuck when I try to follow the installation instructions. When I
execute either `.\configure` or `./configure` in the DOS command line,
I get an error of "unknown command" (even if I am placed in the same directory where the file is stored).

When I execute `.\configure` in PowerShell, I get a message asking me
which programme should be used to open this file.

And here is where I get lost.  :/

I have discovered an alternate path, which is installing GSL from `vcpkg` (https://vcpkg.io/). This is suggested by VS Code, actually. This `vcpkg` seems to be a programme by Microsoft to make it easier to install third-party C/C++ packages in Windows.

The specifications to install `vcpkg` are (https://vcpkg.io/en/getting-started.html):

- Windows 7 or newer
- Git
- Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 or newer

I can try this path, but first I would like to be sure there is no easier way (installing Visual Studio to not really use it seems a lot to me!).

Comment: I have the same doubt. Installing instructions contained in the downloaded file don't help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using GNU Scientific Library (GSL) under Windows x64 with MinGW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30015656/using-gnu-scientific-library-gsl-under-windows-x64-with-mingw)